# Why is my XML file not loading in Websphere Virtual Server?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, xml, jakarta-ee

I am trying to dynamically generate a navigation menu by parsing an xml file with jquery in a Dynamic Web Project in IRAD (eclipse).

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MenuRoot>
    <Menu text="DPP" url="#">
        <SubMenu text="Admin" url="#"></SubMenu>
        <SubMenu text="Listing" url="#"></SubMenu>
        <SubMenu text="Update" url="#"></SubMenu>
    </Menu>
    <Menu text="Waiver" url="#"></Menu>
    <Menu text="Vehicle Inventory" url="#"></Menu>
    <Menu text="About" url="#"></Menu>
    <Menu text="Contact" url="#"></Menu>
</MenuRoot>
```

The jQuery script (embedded in a jsp page):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "WEB-INF/topMenuTemplate.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            var ul_main=$("<ul id=\"nav\" />");
            $(xml).find("Menu").each(function(){
                if($(this).children().length)
                {
                    var ulSub=$("<ul/>");
                    $(this).children().each(function(){
                        ulSub.append("<li><a href="+$(this).attr("url")+">"+$(this).attr("text")+"</a></li>");
                    });
                    var li=$("<li><a href="+$(this).attr("url")+">"+$(this).attr("text")+"</a></li>");
                    ul_main.append(li.append(ulSub));
                }
                else ul_main.append("<li><a href="+$(this).attr("url")+">"+$(this).attr("text")+"</a></li>");
            });
            $("#navbar").append(ul_main);
        }
    });
```

});

Chrome Javascript error:

```
GET http://localhost:9080/ELVISWeb/WEB-INF/topMenuTemplate.xml 404 (Not Found)
```

However when I open the raw xml with chrome it opens fine. It's when I use the virtual server url:

```
http://localhost:9080/ELVISWeb/WEB-INF/topMenuTemplate.xml
```

that I get:

```
Error 404: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /WEB-INF/topMenuTemplate.xml
```

I've also verified multiple times and the path is indeed correct. Is there something I need to enable in WebSphere to allow XML files to be used by jQuery? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot serve files from WEB-INF/ folder, it is forbidden by the specification. Move your topMenuTemplate.xml to the root of the WebContent folder and adjust paths accordingly.